# Need the output in specific format in psql

Tags: sql, concatenation, greenplum

Suppose:-

```
subh=# select 'test123';
          ?column?
-------------------------------------
         test123
```

and

```
subh=# select obj_description('test123'::regclass);
  obj_description
--------------------
 this is my table
```

I am running this query :-

```
subh=# select 'test123' || ' ' || obj_description('test123'::regclass) as test;
             test
 -------------------------------
  test123 this is my table
```

Actually I want the output to be as follows :-

```
            test
-------------------------------
  test123 'this is my table'
```

Comment: `''' ' || obj_description('test123'::regclass) || ''''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `quote_literal`

This function adds the single quote in front and back of given string/number. Read [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).

```
subh=# select 'test123' || ' ' || quote_literal(obj_description('test123'::regclass)) as test;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
subh=# select 'test123' || ' \'' || obj_description('test123'::regclass) as test || '\'';

             test
 -------------------------------
  test123 'this is my table'
```

`\'` will be used for adding quote

Comment: Quotes are **not** escaped using a backslash in SQL, but by doubling them: `'test123' || '''' || ....`